# Zabbix poller processes more than 75% busy

Tags: zabbix

zabbix items 36080 .
Zabbix_proxy,
Zabbix poller processes more than 75% busy not waring everytime.i was add pollers ，but it's not work!

Comment: Did you restart your proxy/server after adding pollers? Please share zabbix screens with poller details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust these two values in the zabbix_server.conf depending on the resources you have at your disposal.

```
 StartPollers=56
 StartPollersUnreachable=10
```